# what is process dependency in asp session state

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I read from [MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) that ASP session state is process dependent and the actions that affect the process also affect session state, where as ASP.Net session state is process independent. Also I have read that since ASP.Net follows `out-of-process model` it supports server farm configurations.

I tried to [search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what%20is%20a%20process%20in%20asp) and figure out what they mean by **process** but out of luck

What is exactly meant by `Process` in that definition?
An example would be helpful for me to understand it better

Answer (score 1):

That means if you are using `InProc` session state then it will be dependent on your apppool. If apppool resets you will loose session. So, to avoid this you can use `State server or Sql server` mode of session state.

Comment: Thanks Amit:) if app pool is getting restarted the entire web application wont be accessible na?

Comment: Thanks Amit Upvoted :) 
if you have any links where i can learn more about this please share

Comment: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/11/22/ASPNET-load-balancing-and-ASPNET-state-server-(aspnet_state).aspx and http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-2-configure-asp-net-settings

Answer (score 1):

In a server farm configuration, you have multiple machines serving the single website. When you use InProc sessions in a server farm, then every server has it's own independent Session state.

When you use stateserver or sqlserver as session store, then session state is stored in a separate server, outside of the webserver process. This store is accessed by all webservers, which means they share the session state.

Comment: thanks @Hans Kesting
Can you please suggest some links where I can learn more about this